# C# Forms Mouse Hover Not firing in controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseover, mousehover

I am trying to write a code on Mouse_Hover for Button

```
private void Button_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Button b = (Button)sender;
    toolTip1.Show("Click ME!!", b);
}
```

But toolTip1 is not showing!!

after this I try to use MouseHover In another controls and it did not work and I try To use
MessageBox , but it did not work even , and I double check Events for Button (and other controls)
in properties tab.

Comment: are you able to hit the breakpoint in`Button_MouseHover`

Comment: I can put breakpoint in `Button_MouseHover` , but it does not give effect when I Debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to wire up controls to use the mouse hover event in order to use a tooltip. [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-tooltips-for-controls-on-a-windows-form-at-design-time) has some useful guidance, the essence of which is "add a tooltip to your form, assign the tooltip to the button"

Comment: I tried to add it to Design and give value for Tooltip on toolTip1 , but it does not working.

Comment: You're saying the advice given in MSDN is incorrect? That is indeed unusual! Did you follow their advice exactly, in a new project? If it works in a new project but not in your existing, then something else conflicts...

Comment: Any thing About `MouseHover` is not working , when i make a new project it works , but after a while it stops working , and I don't know how there will be any conflicts in my program.

Comment: Thank You ♥♥ after thinking about conflicts ,  I Finally Found the Wrong I Redraw my Button and put image on it after deleting images and redrawing function it Works !! Thank  you again Now My Problem is how to disable conflicts and keep image and drawing.

Comment: I solved the conflicts , the error was that i use `b.Image = Image.FromFile(@"imagepath");` , but now i use DrawImage instead of  b.Image. and it works, You Save my life.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to solve your problem:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip toolTip1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);

        Button myBtn = new Button();
        this.Controls.Add(myBtn);

        myBtn.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        myBtn.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(myBtn_MouseEnter);
        myBtn.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(myBtn_MouseLeave);
    }


    void myBtn_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (sender as Button);
        if (btn != null)
        {
            this.toolTip1.Show("Hello!!!", btn);
        }
    }

    void myBtn_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (sender as Button);
        if (btn != null)
        {
            this.toolTip1.Hide(btn);
        }
    }
```